# Redirect to route without get params with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, get, routes, laravel-5.3

I have some legacy urls with get params that I want to redirect to the route without these get parameters.

In my web.php I have:

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'welcome', 'uses' => 'PageController@welcome']);
```

URLs like http://example.com/?page_id=5 should redirect (302) to http://example.com/.

In the controller I tried the following:

```
public function welcome(Request $request)
{
    if($request->has('page_id')) {

        redirect()->to('welcome', 302);
    }

    return view('welcome');
}
```

It reaches the redirect but the the url still has the ?page_id=5 in it. Something like:

```
redirect()->to('welcome', 302)->with('page_id', null);
```

Made no difference as well. What is the best way in Laravel 5.3 to redirect a page with parameters after the ? to one without parameters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `return` in front of the `redirect()` method to make it work:

```
public function welcome(Request $request)
{
    if($request->has('page_id')) {

        return redirect()->route('welcome');
    }

    return view('welcome');
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes it does! It makes a lot of sense ;)

Comment: @Roderik - If you find this answer correct and helpful then accept & upvote this answer as it motivates me to give answers to other questions like this and helps others to quickly find the correct answer!

Comment: I wasn't allowed to accept it immediately, there was a delay for it (prob. linked to reputation).

Comment: No problem, I just informed you, by the way thanks! :D